# How to visualize graph with different data types: boolean & integer?

Tags: info-visualisation, graphs

I have two variables:

- **A** is an integer from 0-1000u (u=some arbitrary unit)
- **B** is either 1 or 0

I need to visualize a graph (or graphs) to show the relationship of **A & B** (y-axis) against **t** (time; x-axis) and also relationship between **A & B**

I tried showing them on one graph, but having Boolean and integer value on the same y-axis looks incorrect.

I could just do 2 separate graphs: **A/t** & **B/t** but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of visualizing this which also shows the relationship between A & B more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You might get better answer at [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but I'd use a graph with two y-axis. One axis with values from 0 to 1000 and the other with values 0 to 1. Having values from 0 to 1000 shown as line and values from 0 to 1 as bars results in the following graph. Presenting the boolean value as stepped line might be more suitable though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the binary variable to be represented by background color (see mockup below). This way, it would provide context, or tight spatial relationship, with the numeric variable line over it.

[image: chart proposal]